# SQL how to make that beside default value, there could be only other value

Tags: mysql, sql

If there is default set to 'Always', using check I think, only other possible value would be let's say 'Honorary'? Simplest way. If this was JavaScript I'd use `if (default){value='Always'}else{value='Honorary'}` How do I do that in MySql? Also do you know how to set min value of the colon int to be let's say 0. Like from 0 to 999?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a check constraint, which is supported in the most recent versions of MySQL:

```
alter table t add constraint chk_t_value check (value in ('Always', 'Honorary'));
```

Another option is to use an `enum` that only takes on two values.